# Android P2P how does client get to know that a connection is been established with device

Tags: android, sockets, p2p

I have looked into P2P API provided by android. I know all the steps to discover peers and connect to them. My question is how does other device know that a connection has been created by some device to my device? bcz after connection we use sockets to transfer data. for sockets to work, client must know the ip and port of server. does this asdress needs to be entered manually on client side?
My app's flow should be like device A discovers devices and one or more devices may have my app installed on them. A selects one device and send connection request. Other device can accepts/rejects the request. If accepted then both devices should be connected through sockets one as server and other of course client.
I hope I explained well what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently building an app like this and can't tell you the "best way" to streamline this process, but you may want to look into making P2P a service because that prevents it from being terminated/paused with the application.

If you choose not to go that route, however, you could use an adapter to auto-update a listView that contains all of the connected devices to your device as well as their addresses.

```
public class myActivity extends Activity
{
    WifiP2pManager.Channel myChannel; //This channel is created and passed to system services in order for WIFI_P2P to work
    WifiP2pManager myManager; //This manager is declared to get the required channel object
    List connections;//connections holds all of the connections that the host is dealing with.
    ListView listView;//listView which we will use to display progress bars
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;//adapter which is used to update and display the connections
```

...

```
protected void onCreate
{
    connections = new ArrayList();//make an arraylist for the connections
    connections.add("No Connected Devices");//say there's no connections as a default
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.connectionsListView);//initialize the list view
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, connections);//create an array adapter
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);//attach the adapter to the listView
```

And finally, in your receiver (specifically in your WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION section)

```
public class myBroadcastReceiver
{
    else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action))
    {
        // This is when new connections or disconnections occur
        //WifiP2pInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_INFO);
        WifiP2pGroup group = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_GROUP);
        myActivity.connections.clear();
        myActivity.connections.addAll(group.getClientList());
        if(myActivity.connections.size() == 0)
        {
            myActivity.connections.add("No Connected Devices");
        }
        myActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Should you want the connected devices' addresses, you simply call connections[index].deviceAddress.